# common lisp array and hashtable oddity?

Tags: hashtable, common-lisp

I am trying to store attack moves for chess pieces in a 64 square [bitboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard). Basically I am using any array of hash-tables to do this:

```
(defvar attacks (make-array '(64) :initial-element (make-hash-table))
```

However, I have noticed that when I fill up each hashtable in the array (with about 1000 elements each) it intersects with another hashtable. That is one hashtable has values from another hashtable, even though I didn't put it there.

Am I imagining things? Is this a bug?

Comment: You are not imagining things. It is not a bug in-so-far as the language is concerned (it does exactly what you asked of it, it creates an array of 64 elements, each element being the same hash table).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a single hash table (with make-hash-table) that you then set in all elements of an array. To do what you want, you'd want to do one of:

- Create an empty array, loop through and set each index to a fresh hash table
- Create a list of 64 fresh hash tables and use :INITIAL-CONTENTS to populate the array on creation

That way, the hash tables would be separate instead of the same hash table stored 64 times.

Comment: One easy way: (map-into (make-array 64) 'make-hash-table).

Answer (score 0):

You should use :INITFORM instead of :initial-element to get different hashtables

(My answer is wrong, see Vatine's)

Comment: I get the error message that INITFORM is not a valid keyword.

Comment: I see. I mixed it up with CLOS. So I am wrong. But the problem you have is probably that your initialisation argument is evaluated only once, so you get only one hash-table.